# Find unused PHP files in a local directory

Tags: javascript, php, command-line-interface

I am starting work on a very large legacy project that didn't use SCCS. Subsequently, there are hundreds of files that are dated. When I say dated, I don't mean old, I mean `index.march.2013.php`. Hundreds of them. So I'm looking for a program that could run on the CLI to search the directories recursively for unused PHP file. Something like a `find` grep + regex searching for `require`, `include`, or `require_once`. An alternative idea I have is to run a crawler on the site and check for when last accessed at the filesystem level, though I'm not entirely sure if that's possible. I think `atime` flag might help, and I'm assuming `require` and `include`.

My plan is to do a master commit, and then a cleaned new branch with the removal of PHP, and then with other readily available tools, a removal of the static assets.

Has anyone come across a program or utility that might highlight which PHP files are old and unused?

**EDIT**

This is on Linux.

Comment: Is this on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Linux. (Edited question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get a list of files that are used:

```
grep -R -e 'require(\|require_once(\|include(' * | cut -d':' -f2 | awk -F"(" '{print $2}' | awk -F")" '{print $1}' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | awk -F'"' '{print $1}' | awk -F"'" '{print $1}'
```

then you could use `find | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'` to get a list of all files. Redirect the two commands to different files then do a `diff` or `comm` on the two files